# .xcdatamodel: cdtool cannot compile

Tags: xcode, core-data

This problem occurred right after the last update of OS X El Capitan 10.11 beta 6, Xcode 7 beta 4 compiles my projects with the error in .xcdatamodel file saying:
`cdtool cannot compile`. 
I tried to compile the same projects on OS X Yosemite and with Xcode 7.0 beta 4 I get always the same compilation error.
Any idea on how to clear this issue?
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One solution posted on the Apple developer forums is renaming a file within the iOS Simulator.

```
cd /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
cd Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform  
cd Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib  
sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
```

Here's the original [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/36684#36684).

Comment: Works for me too Using Xcode 7.0 beta 5 (7A176x) (latest beta at the time of writing).

Comment: Don't work for Xcode 7.0.1: "mv: dyld_sim: No such file or directory"

Comment: The original link said the destination renamed file is **dyld_sim.orig**, not **dyld_sim.rig**. Which one?

Comment: @Itachi makes no difference, you're renaming it so that it wouldn't be found. It can be `dyld_sim.whatever`.

Comment: @MorganWilde I am facing the same issue for xcode 11 beta 6. Please refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590075/getting-error-cdtool-cannot-compile0-on-xcode-11-beta-6

Comment: @ChikabuZ How did you resolve this issue because I am getting same error. Please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590075/getting-error-cdtool-cannot-compile0-on-xcode-11-beta-6

Comment: @iPhone Sorry, I don't remember. But anyway please try with stable Xcode (10.3)

Answer (score 8):

This solution unfortunately did not work for me.  However, I had recently changed some tables around in core data.  I found the culprit by looking at all of my relationships and their inverses.  One of the inverses had a dead reference.  Switched it to "no inverse" did a clean and was up and running again.  Hope this helps someone else.
[image]

Comment: True, I had a similar problem with a fetched property, I think that this issue comes when there is something wring with the core data model.

Comment: This answer solved for me. I had deleted a relationship but didn't delete the inverse. This answer prompted me to do so... Thanks

Comment: I had an issue with a duplicated association in my model after a Git merge. Fixing that solved this error.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I changed the name of a property that was being used in a fetched property predicate.  (So the predicate could no longer compile)

Fixing the typo in the predicate and rebuilding the project fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error because of wrongly configured Constraints for properties. I'm not sure about what was wrong, but remove and re-add the constraints, the error disappear.

**Obs**: When i say constraints for properties, i'm telling about this:

[image]