# .xcdatamodel: cdtool cannot compile with Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, compiler-errors

I'm using Xcode 7.2 on OSX 10.11.3.
I couldn't build and run a project which uses CoreData.

I have come across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849881/xcdatamodel-cdtool-cannot-compile), but it doesn't seem to work for me. I have changed the file's name by hand and the error still persisted.

These are my screenshots:

I have changed the filename

[image: I have changed the filename]

The error persists

[image: The error persists]

P/S: I disabled the System Integrity Protection by using this command `csrutil enable --without debug` to make the Xfinder plugin works on my computer. I also tried to reenable but still no luck.  I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the error.

Comment: @TomHarrington I tried to do what you said, and nothing happened. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled Xcode and problem solved.

Comment: this solution didn't work for me, if your .xcdatamodeld is under version control, try rolling back the changes. Worked for me.