# XCode 7.2.1 - cdtool cannot compile occurs irregularly

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

The app I am developing has a weird issue since a few months. Sometimes during building an archive the error `cdtool cannot compile` occurs. But only sometimes.
When I wipe the derived-data and do a clean-archive it works again.

I found a variety of people asking similar questions, but they all had this error occur nonstop.

To be precise: The error occurs always during archiving and always on the same file which is **Config.xcdatamodel**. This CoreData model only has one version so version-conflicts aren't a problem (also verified on the file-system).

Unfortunately it is nearly not reproducable at all, it seems to occur 100% randomly. It also doesn't provide an closer information about what exactly it is, that fails.

[image]

In the image there are two compile-errors. Thats because the **Config.xcdatamodel** that fails, is in both targets. They won't be used at the same time, so it should be fine. I also suspect that the second error-message is based on the first (upper) one.

Did anyone ever observe such a behaviour? I'm currently using XCode 7.2.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849881/xcdatamodel-cdtool-cannot-compile

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried this, without effect