# Getting error "cdtool cannot compile[0]" on Xcode 11 beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I just migrated to Xcode 11 beta 6 and just running my project but I am getting error:

> .xcdatamodel 'cdtool cannot compile[0]'

I have already referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849881/xcdatamodel-cdtool-cannot-compile). But after writing command in terminal I got message "mv:dyld_sim:No such file or directory".

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?